# How to join two SQL Server tables

Tags: sql-server

I have a two tables:

**usermaster**

```
Id int pk, name varchar
```

**monytranfer**

```
TId int pk, sender int references usermaster (id), receiver int references usermaster(id), amount
```

How do I join these two tables to get the below columns?

```
TId, sendername, receivername, amount
```

Thanks.

Comment: Here [Sql Server Tutorial](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/index.php) and here [Join In Sql Server Tutorial](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/joins.php) but i would prefer you learn the concept first. Now do your best and good luck..

Answer (score 3):

As per my understanding you monytranfer table has two columns which are referring to the same column of user master right. i have written the sql query for that.

```
Select 
    m.Tid, u1.name as SenderName, u2.name as ReceiverName, m.amount
from 
    monytranfer m 
join 
    usermaster u1 on u1.id = m.sender
join 
    usermaster u2 on u2.id = m.receiver;
```

Is this what you want ? Inform me if it solves your problem.